An investigation on the rate of degradation (in %) of Chrysoidine-Y dye, as measured by UV-Vis spectrophotometry
Planning to do an investigation on the rate of degradation (in %) of Chrysoidine-Y dye, using UV-Vis spectrophotometry. I am planning to take an approach of increasing the concentration of Hydrogen Peroxide (H2O2) in a Fenton reaction, at different pH levels, and then see its effect on the degradation.
Could someone please let me know wheter this investigation is possible! I have seen such an investigation before with other dyes, for instance Methylene Blue and Methyl orange. Also could someone please suggest any procedure/literature which has done such an experiment/investigation before, for Chrysoidine-Y dye.
Thanks!

The idea is not bad, but you have to search similar ideas yourself. Have you used Google Scholar and Google Books?

Yeah, I did. But the thing is as part of my assignment, I need existing literature. I did find literature for the Fenton reaction in the degradation of Methylene Blue and Methyl orange, but in the case of Chrysoidine-Y dye, it was limited. Regardless, from the limited research I could find through open access, it is safe to say that H2O2 conc. in the fenton reaction and pH does have an effect on the Chrysoidine-Y dye. I guess preliminary experiments are the only way to find out, at the moment.

Yes, you actually study the related articles, and then try to apply those ideas on a new dye. That is the essence of new research. Think like this dye, let me try my own dye instead of methylene blue? What would the results look like?
